# How to see the request's POST contents in Android Studio network profiler?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio 3's network profiler we cannot see the contents of the POST section. We can see the request uri, so contents of GET works just fine okay. We can see the response.
But contents of POST is not there.

Is there anyway to see it?

Answer (score 2):

Okay it turns out, it is actually coming up soon as a new feature:
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/12/android-studio-31-canary-5-is-now.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip!